# extend partition from within terminal

Tags: terminal, partition, ext4

I would like to extend n1p2 with n1p1. n1p1 has no data on it. n1p2 has my work data . The end result would be a 111GB ext4. I was wondering if it was possible to do it from the terminal or is it possible only when booting with a usb disk? Thanks!

Terminal:

```
--nvme0n1p1 ntfs 55.9G Second
--nvm0n1p2 ext4 55.9G /
```

Comment: 1. [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself **into your question** and format it as code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K or by using the editor's `{}` icon.  2. it's possible to do from the command line, but only while the partitions aren't in use (i.e. aren't mounted).  Since one of them is the root partition, that's only going to be the case when you've booted another OS.   So, boot [gparted](https://gparted.org) from a CD or USB

Comment: BTW, I usually prefer to use command line tools and avoid most GUI system tools like the plague that they are, but I much prefer to use `gparted` rather than do all the track & sector calculations manually.  gparted is **much** less likely to make a mistake than I am.  It automates resizing and moving partitions, and does it correctly with no fuss and no drama.   I have my tftp server set up with gparted as one of the menu options (also have clonezilla and debian installer and others), so I can boot it on any of my machines over the network.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I thought. Consider making it an answer. Many people wonder if that's possible. Including some at my workplace.

Comment: The same question has been asked here many times, with similar answers given.  I know it's a dupe, but I don't have time right now to hunt for a dupe to close it with.